# Attempt to call a function in C# from a C Dll

Tags: c#, c, dllimport, rhapsody

I coded a simple sum function using Rhapsody Developer in C and declared it as `__declspec(dllexport) int Class_Sum_sum(Class_Sum* const me, int a, int b);` in my C file. I am a total beginner in C# programming.

My C# program looks like this:

```
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;


namespace Test1_C_Sharp
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            int x = Win32.Class_Sum_sum(5, 8);
            textBox1.Text = x.ToString();
        }
    }

    public class Win32
    {
        [DllImport("CalcSum.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
        public static extern int Class_Sum_sum(int a, int b);

    }

}
```

When i execute this code, i get a Form with a textbox and "sum" button, as expected, when i press the "sum" button, an exception is thrown saying that

> PInvokeStackImbalance was detected

which actually makes sense because i have three arguments in my C function (Class_sum *,int,int) and I do not know what exactly the first argument in my C# code should look like.

Does anyone know the right way to do this?

EDIT: I modelled my class "Class_sum" in IBM Rhapsody which translates to a `struct` in C. A snippet from my H file like this:

```
/*## class Class_Sum */
typedef struct Class_Sum Class_Sum;
struct Class_Sum {
    RiCReactive ric_reactive;
    int op1;        /*## attribute op1 */
    int op2;        /*## attribute op2 */
    int sum;        /*## attribute sum */
    /*#[ ignore */
    int rootState_subState;
    int rootState_active;
    int MainState_subState;
    /*#]*/ 
  ......
  ......
};
```

Rhapsody generates its own functions and structures like `me` for instance, which translates to `this` in an OOP Language.

Comment: We would need to see details of the Class_Sum to be able to full help here. This would need to be declared in your C# code & an instance created & passed to the function. Another reason for the stack imbalance can be different calling conventions - either _cdecl or __stdcall - you need to [ensure that they match](https://manski.net/2012/05/pinvoke-tutorial-basics-part-1/#stack-imbalance).

Comment: You will need to study up on marshalling c structs/classes - try these links : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/interop/marshaling-classes-structures-and-unions & https://limbioliong.wordpress.com/2011/06/03/passing-structures-between-managed-and-unmanaged-code/. With classes containing simple types such as int,, double etc - this is quite easy - but if the structs contain more complex types such as strings, arrays & other classes then correct marshalling can be very difficult. Is there a particular reason you want to try something so complex?

Comment: Thanks so much for the ideas, in my C# program I created a dummy struct Class_sum, created an instance of it (or should I say object) and passed this instance as the first argument in the function call, and it works as expected.

Comment: @AbelTom, do you often need to call unmanaged functions from C#? The data marshalling can get quite grueling as complexity goes up. There are better alternatives out there. For example, check out [C++/CLI] (https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/19354/Quick-C-CLI-Learn-C-CLI-in-less-than-minutes). Data marashalling is built into it and happens in the background. Converting data types regardless of complexity is a piece of cake.

Answer (score 0):

you have to put the third parameter and because it is a pointer in C# you have to use the word ref

```
public static extern int Class_Sum_sum(ref Class_Sum parameterName,int a, int b)
```